# Detect when a Window has stopped moving?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Does anyone know how to detect if a Win32(c++) window has stopped moving?

WM_MOVE detects when the window is moving, but how does one detect when it has *stopped* moving?

Comment: You don't really know it's moving, all you know is that is *has moved*. The difference is subtle.

Comment: So, WM_MOVE triggers when the window is not moving? Edit: You are right.

Comment: Yes, Sent after a window has been moved. [WM_MOVE message (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632631(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The windows message you wish to handle is `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`.

[WM_EXITSIZEMOVE message (Windows) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632623.aspx)

Depending on what you wish to accomplish, there's also the possibility that you might be better served by reacting to `WM_NCLBUTTONUP`, which is sent when the mouse button is released in the non-client areas of a window, such as the title bar of any window with a caption, border chrome, etc.

[WM_NCLBUTTONUP message (Windows) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645621.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, extrodinarily helpful!

Comment: You're welcome. Also, just in case you haven't heard of it, Spy++/Spyxx is quite useful for debugging and tracing such windows messages. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460760.aspx